# How to insert the interpunct character in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, special-characters

Does anyone know how I can insert the [interpunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct) character (also known as midline decimal) in Ubuntu? The combination mentioned in the Wikipedia article does not seem to work:

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: AltGr + .  works fine for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, then type `00b7` <kbd>Enter</kbd>, i.e. the Unicode value of interpunct character.

Comment: The `00` is not necessary.

Comment: How does one memorize this ? What about the Compose key ?

Answer (score 9):

The default way to do this is given in the [Ubuntu Help page: The Gtk Dead Key Compose Table](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkDeadKeyTable). The sequence for the middle dot is: <kbd>ThirdLevel Chooser</kbd> + <kbd>DeadKey-Cirucmflex</kbd> + <kbd>period</kbd> or expanded: <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>. This is supposed to work even without changing keyboard options.

Compose key combinations, however, did not work reliably on my system until I set a compose key in the Keyboard Layout.

*Settings* > *Keyboard Layout* > *Options* > Expand *Compose Key Position* and choose the key you want. I chose *RightAlt* so now, <kbd>RightAlt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> (now in 3rd level) + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> inserts the middle dot.

Comment: +1 for the use of the underrated Compose key! Much easier to remember than hexadecimal unicode values of characters.

Comment: What does it mean to press `Shift` twice in a row?

Comment: @Ruslan I don't think the first press of Shift is necessary as outlined in chakes response. It works simply by tapping and releasing the designated Compose key then hold Shift + ^ together (for the tilde char - shifted 6) release then tap . to insert the middle dot. A three step movement.

Comment: @Ruslan Sorry I couldn't get back to you earlier. It mean alt+shift then release, then the rest of the sequence. This was to get into the 3rd level chooser. I tested this a lot at the time at it sure seemed necessary. But Graham is correct that it now no longer appears necessary. Just compose+shift+^+.

Answer (score 1):

Copy an interpunct · from Wikipedia or anywhere. Paste and save it in a document on your desktop. Copy from there and paste when you need to use it.
Or, from your word processing program's toolbar, go to insert, select special character, choose the raised dot (6th row down, 12th over in Microsoft Works), and change the font size to whatever you want it to be. It isn't perfect (it's much lower than an actual interpunct) but it's a little higher than a period. 
Also the lower case letter l in both wingdings and webdings makes a black dot but it isn't much higher than a period. Lower case h in Marlett makes a similar dot, but quite a bit larger and Marlett keeps inserting a box for a blank space, which is kind of a nuisance. You could type all the upper and lower case keys on your keyboard, then try out each font in your system to see if any of them produce a better looking "interpunct."

Here is a larger interpunct if you would like to copy it for pasting elsewhere:
interpunct • interpunct

Answer (score 1):

I use US international layout and I can write the interpunct with AltGR + . (release all the keys) and then the keys that needs the interpunct. For example the interpunct between the two Ls in "Paraŀlel"

Comment: This is not an interpunct but a letter with a dot (like an accent). In case of L/l: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C4%BF
For s it would be ṡ etc.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE : using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

you can find in the layout of your keyboard all the keys (see illustration below). In my case with a french keyboard it is pressing the following keys : <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The raised dot (·) is included in the polytonic Greek keyboard, the dot is useful as one types ancient greek. Below is an example with the keyboard installed on Ubuntu. You would press: Level (or AltGR) + q

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your keyboard settings. With 105 keys keyboard in German Layout the combination is

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>  (comma).

Answer (score 0):

On my computer the command `grep periodcentered /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US-UTF8/Compose` outputs the following combinations

- `<Multi_key> <period> <minus>        : "·"   periodcentered # MIDDLE DOT`
- `<Multi_key> <period> <asciicircum>  : "·"   periodcentered # MIDDLE DOT`
- `<Multi_key> <asciicircum> <period>  : "·"   periodcentered # MIDDLE DOT`
- `<dead_circumflex> <period>          : "·"   periodcentered # MIDDLE DOT`

`<Multi_key>` stands  for the <kbd>Compose</kbd> key, configured in `/etc/default/keyboard`.
This translates into the *sequences* (no simultaneous keystrokes required)

- <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd>
- <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>
- <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>
- <kbd><sup>^</sup></kbd><kbd>.</kbd> on keyboards with dead circumflex key (French, German, Spanish)