# How to have a key or an easy shortcut writing the interpunct "·"?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I recently got Linux installed and I noticed that it was kind of difficult to make the interpunct (middle dot): "·". I would like to find a way to either directly replacing a key value (let's say the <kbd>$</kbd> key) by the interpunct OR to have an easier shortcut (let's say <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) to write it. On Windows I had found a software that made it possible but I haven't succeed in finding something similar on Linux (for now!). Is there any software that enables it? Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

No software required for this.

It is simply done by pressing and holding the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key and pressing the full stop character above it as this demonstrates ····

[image]

The interpunct will be placed in the centre of the line.

In the event that your keyboard doesn't support the key combination to insert the interpunct (like the French AZERTY keyboard) an alternative - if not perfect solution - is to try [this resource](https://www.alt-codes.net/bullet_alt_codes.php) of bullet symbols. its a work around but might work in your situation. If you click on the item you need, it will be copied to your clipboard and then Ctrl+v (or right mouse click - Paste) will post it in for you: •

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's unfortunately not working. I'm using a french keyboard layout, that might be the reason!

Comment: @Guigeek if you are using a standard AZERTY keyboard, the Alt Gr key is to the right of the spacebar and the full stop is above the semicolon so you would need to use the Maj key as you are pressing the semicolon key. http://kbd-intl.narod.ru/english/layouts. You can also use Ctrl + Alt to get the Alt Gr key.

Comment: I only get a "×" while pressing "Alt Gr" and ".", with or without "shift". I'm indeed using a standard azerty keyboard (so as you wrote: with the "Alt Gr" right of the space bar). I saw on [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236974/how-to-insert-the-interpunct-character-in-ubuntu#236994) that it wasn't easy to type an interpunct.

Comment: Another thought. It might be worth opening a terminal and typing showkey -a to see what values (in ascii) are produced from various keypresses. 194 0302 0xc2 and 183 0267 0xb7 is sent by the Alt Gr+fullstop on my kbd. Will the colon key produce the same code?

Comment: I get 195 0303 0xc3 and 151 0227 0x97!

Comment: Ah well. Worth a try. Sorry it didn't help.

Comment: Have a try at this: https://www.alt-codes.net/bullet_alt_codes.php its a work around but might work in your situaion. If you click on the item you need, it will copy iy yo the clipboard and then Ctrl v will past it in for you: • If that works for you let me know and I will amend the answer accordingly specific to a French keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It works but it's still unperfect since I often need to copy other sentences while writing. So I would need to copy the symbol each time again after having copied sth else.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on the French forum of the community, see [here](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2018943&p=2).
I couldn't do an interpunct with the keyboard layout I was using: "Français (variante obsolète)". With another keyboard layout, "Français (variante)", it becomes possible to write an interpunct using `Shift` + `Alt Gr` + `;`.